# What is the need to subclass UIView instead of writing everything in ViewController

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I went through lot of similar questions but still have not clearly understood this.

In terms of better design - what is right way - creating all the UIButtons, UILabels etc in the view controller itself and then add them as subviews, or should I create a custom view (@interface MyView : UIView) with all the required buttons/labels etc and then assign that view to the view property of View controller? I am not using interface builder.

Is there any real need/advantage of creating a custom view like this or adding everything in view controller itself should be okay/good idea? Sorry I am very new to iOS app development :-)

If someone could explain it to me - would be really helpful.

Comment: Subclassing `UIView` alone is not always the best option, often you'll want to go further by creating fabrics, data-models and other stuff for subviews. Do you have a favorite writer ? Imagine all his books are merged into one huge file where you need special contents to read  separate contents of the real contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some advantages of subclassing a view are:

1. Code separation. If you have a complex view and want to keep your viewcontroller clean, subclass and separate it out.
2. Reuse. If you reuse the view anywhere else it is possible with minimal effort when the view is it's own class.
3. You can choose what setup and methods to expose for setup

Some disadvantages of subclassing a view are:

1. View no longer will have access to view controller ivars.
2. View controller will no longer have direct manipulation on the view
3. You are constrained to what the view publicly exposes in terms of setup and config (may be a good thing).

Overall, there is no single best answer, it all depends on your setup and how you like to keep your project organized.

Comment: One thing not mentioned is there are times when you must create a custom view. If the view needs to do custom drawing in a `drawRect:` method, then you must subclass `UIView`. This is about the only time that you *must* subclass `UIView`. But there are plenty of times when you *should*.

Comment: Thanks but can you please elaborate. I will tell you briefly what I am trying to build. I have a main view where i have sign-in, register buttons and short description of what the app is about and then there are scroll view to demonstrate the 'How it works' part. Then there will be few more (3-4) views that will have 'not very complicated' things - about the actual app. Given that do you recommend creating seperate/custom UIView's for all the views (and a corresponding) UIViewController or just have all in 4-5 UIViewControllers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My non-answer : the answer lies in between these 2 opposite sides :

- putting verything in the view Controller, using just basic views
- using very elaborate views that abstract away some tedious graphic work.

To get an idea of what I'm talking about : one might implement a `UITableView` behaviour directly into a `UIViewController` with just a `UIScrollView`, and handle all the indexPath computation (depending on the amount of scrolling), views recycling, etc... in this very viewController.

But, as lists are a common way to visually display information, all this 'recycling view', 'setting content for currently displayed cells'  has been moved into a custom view class : `UITableView`, and delegate and datasource patterns have been use to make this class behavior easily customizable.

Creating abstractions has its advantages and disadvantages.
I try to do things incrementally :

- hold the most you can in viewController
- when code becomes too complex, or if you see yourself needind the same kind of 'component' elsewhere : the create a custom view, and try to define its API (what properties it exposes, what implementation it hides)

Comment: Since this is one of the first few test apps I am building and the views are not very complex, I would - as you suggested will go with adding subviews in View Controller and then later as I start building relatively complex apps will start thinking of creating custom views.

Answer (score 0):

View controllers are a nice way of separating the things that a **view must do** in the strict sense (handle input, render output) from the **larger hierarchy, manipulation, and information routing of views around it**, which the view controller coordinates.

Striking the right balance depends on a number of localized factors. A view which contains a label and an image (like a cell) could certainly "own" its subviews and appear to the controller like one container unit. But note in this case that the subviews are also supporting the input/rendering of the "cell" unit.

In that sense, if you have a large canvas with a set of actual controls that are "on top" of that canvas but not necessarily "owned" by it, the view controller would probably want to create and attach these into the view hierarchy.